# Prove the following relationship of the number e and then show that it is irrational

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I have been trying to show the following fact:

$$e -(1+\frac{1}{1!}+ ... + \frac{1}{n!})<\frac{1}{nn!}$$

My steps:
it seems reasonable to me to try to do this problem by induction, but when I tried it I came up with the following:

inductive hypothesis: satisfies for n.

for the case n+1 we will have to

$e -(1+\frac{1}{1!}+ ... + \frac{1}{n!} + \frac{1}{(n+1)!}) = e -(1+\frac{1}{1!}+ ... + \frac{1}{n!}) - \frac{1}{(n+1)!} < \frac{1}{nn!} - \frac{1}{(n+1)!} =\frac{1}{n(n+1)!} $

but in the last inequality I got that it was between (n+1) but I am looking for it to be divided by n, how could I complete the proof? Any clues or ideas?

Finally, once this inequality is obtained, it is simple if the inequality is multiplied by n! We can consider an n large enough such that there would have to be an integer between $0$ and $1$, which would be a contradiction when assuming that e is rational.

Comment: Can you define what $\epsilon$ is? Also, can't you use [this estimate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398493/showing-that-the-eulers-number-is-irrational?noredirect=1)? Please use MathJax everywhere.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Sorry it's the number e, not really the problem asks me to first show that relationship and then use it to see that e is irrational

Comment: Induction might be difficult here, try considering the partial sums of $e$'s Taylor expansion instead.

Comment: @WillowWisp I (not the original poster) am able to prove that the assertion is true against any partial sums of $~e$'s Taylor expansion.  However, that is insufficient to prove the assertion against $~e.~$  For example, $~\displaystyle \forall ~n, ~1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^n} < 2.~$  However, the limit, as $~n \to \infty,~$ of the partial sums is equal to $~2.$

Comment: @DietrichBurde Re my previous comment, I (also) am stumped as to how you can show the inequality against the limit of the partial sums, as $~n \to \infty.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

appears you need $ \frac{1}{(n+1)!} +  \frac{1}{(n+2)!} + ... $  as
$$   \frac{1}{n!}  \left( \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} +  \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)} +...    \right) <   \frac{1}{n!}  \left( \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} +  \frac{1}{(n+1)^3}...    \right) $$

The geometric series sums to
$$ \frac{\frac{1}{n+1}}{1 -  \frac{1}{n+1}  } = \frac{\frac{1}{n+1}}{   \frac{n+1 -1}{n+1}  } = \frac{\frac{1}{n+1}}{   \frac{n}{n+1}  } = \frac{1}{n}$$

so
$$ \frac{1}{(n+1)!} +  \frac{1}{(n+2)!} + ...  < \frac{1}{n!} \left( \frac{1}{n} \right) $$